# Type error: event is undefined in firefox about javascript

Tags: javascript, events, undefined

Here is the thing.
I'm need to open a new tab and draw something on the new opened tab.

I add event listener like that:

```
div3.addEventListerner("onmousedown",MouseDown(NewWindow.event),false);
```

But the firefox throw errors about the code in the MouseDown() function when the page is loading. The error is not throwed when I move the mouse.

```
function MouseDown(event)
{
if(!event)
    {
    var event = window.event;
    }

X = event.pageX;//Throw error here.
Y = event.pageY;
```

So, there is anyone who knows how to fix this Problem?????

Comment: You've mis-spelt addEventListener. Fix this first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `var` from `var event = window.event`. The variable is already declared (as an argument), so re-declaring it with `var` can only lead to problems.

To be specific, due to hoisting, here is what your code boils down to:

```
function MouseDown(event) {
    var event; // = undefined
    if( !event) { // always true
        event = window.event; // undefined in modern browsers
    }
    X = event.pageX; // ERROR!
}
```

Without the `var`, all is well!

Comment: Yo should mention that `div3.addEventListerner("onmousedown",MouseDown(NewWindow.event),false);` has problems too

Comment: What's the point to check the `event` argument for browsers, which don't even support `addEventListener`?

Comment: Also, JS doesn't re-declare variables ([example](http://jsfiddle.net/wnrkG/)). Declarations are hoisted, and if `var`s are met later in the code, they are ignored.

Answer (score 0):

When you're using [`addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener), `Event` object is passed automatically in all browsers supporting the said method. However, you're calling your eventhandler immediately in argument. Instead you should pass a reference:

```
div3.addEventListener("mousedown", MouseDown, false);
```

Notice also `"mousedown"` without `on`. In the handlerfunction, `event` always exists, no need to check it for older IEs, since they don't support `addEventListener`.